# Issue with mouse events on three.js iframe

Tags: javascript, canvas, iframe, three.js

Click events work as they should, however when mouse drag events are fired (on this example happens when dragging video timestamp), mouse coordinates dont' seem to translate to 2d space of iframe correctly. It seems that x coordinate is doubled from what it should be.

On other embedded websites, due to displacement of y coordinate, during selecting symbols to copy, website scrolls to the bottom of the page.

How can I fix this issue?

Minimal example https://codepen.io/asjas/pen/pWawPm

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var Element = function ( id, x, y, z, ry ) {
  var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
  div.style.width = '480px';
  div.style.height = '360px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
  var iframe = document.createElement( 'iframe' );
  iframe.style.width = '480px';
  iframe.style.height = '360px';
  iframe.style.border = '0px';
  iframe.src = [ 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/', id, '?rel=0'   ].join( '' );
  div.appendChild( iframe );
  var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( div );
  object.position.set( x, y, z );
  object.rotation.y = ry;
  return object;
};

    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
      var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
        camera.position.set( 500, 350, 750 );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        var group = new THREE.Group();
        group.add( new Element( 'xBOqwRRj82A', 0, 0, 240, 0 ) );
        group.add( new Element( 'x4q86IjJFag', 240, 0, 0, Math.PI / 2 ) );
        group.add( new Element( 'JhngfOK_2-0', 0, 0, - 240, Math.PI ) );
        group.add( new Element( 'Grg3461lAPg', - 240, 0, 0, - Math.PI / 2 ) );
        scene.add( group );
        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
        controls.rotateSpeed = 4;
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    
        // Block iframe events when dragging camera
        var blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
        blocker.style.display = 'none';
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function () { blocker.style.display = ''; } );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function () { blocker.style.display = 'none'; } );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
          camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame( animate );
          controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```